# Dealing with float precision in Javascript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, double, floating-accuracy, numerical-methods

I have a large amount of numeric values `y` in javascript.  I want to group them by rounding them down to the nearest multiple of `x` and convert the result to a string.

How do I get around the annoying floating point precision?

For example:

```
0.2 + 0.4 = 0.6000000000000001
```

Two things I have tried:

```
>>> y = 1.23456789 
>>> x = 0.2 
>>> parseInt(Math.round(Math.floor(y/x))) * x; 
1.2000000000000002
```

and:

```
>>> y = 1.23456789 
>>> x = 0.2 
>>> y - (y % x)
1.2000000000000002
```

Comment: This is actually normal behavior for `double` you just don't see it in print statements in most languages. Have you tried rounding your numbers?

Comment: You can't really "get around" it, as it's an intrinsic aspect of binary floating-point math systems. That's true for both your "x" and your "y" values, apparently; if "x" is 0.3 that can't be represented exactly. "Rounding" to arbitrary fractions is going to result in imprecision.

Comment: So what would be an alternative way of converting `y` to `"1.2"`.

Comment: @Jeroen I'm sure you've got it already, but just for the record, `Math.floor(y)`.

Comment: @pilau that would result in 1, not 1.2

Comment: `Math.floor(y*10)/10`?

Comment: i solved multiplying number *1000000, parse int and at the end dividing 1000000. es: (parseint(0.2 * 100000) + parseint(0.4 * 100000)) / 100000

Answer (score 184, accepted):

From this post: [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem)

You have a few options:

- Use a special datatype for decimals, like [decimal.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/)
- Format your result to some fixed number of significant digits, like this:

`(Math.floor(y/x) * x).toFixed(2)`

- Convert all your numbers to integers

Comment: "Convert all your numbers to integers", I've wondered about this. As we know, JavaScript has one number type `Number`, an IEEE 754 float. If that's the case, then why does converting a float to an integer work, (and it does)? Does JavaScript actually have an integer data type that simply isn't accessible via a reserved word?

Comment: IEEE 754 can exactly represent integers up to something like 2^50.  So, if you're working within a known range, you can scale your values to take advantage of the 50 bits (or whatever) of precision, instead of wasting the precision normally reserved for large numbers.

Comment: @richremer a floating point has the property that the accuracy (for normal values) does not depend on the size. - So whether you convert it to integers (by say multiplying the values with some constant) the accuracy is equal.

Comment: The number of "significant digits" is the number of digits using the scientific notation (no leading or trailing zeros) and it's a choice based on circumstances.
- toPrecision's argument seems to be a number of significant digits.
- toFixed is for a number of trailing digits.

Comment: toFixed() will convert the number to a string.

Comment: Note about IEE 754 and @richremer 's comment about JS precision. The limit of integer precision in Javascript is: `(2^53) - 1` or `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`

Answer (score 7):

<strike>You could do something like this</strike>:

```
> +(Math.floor(y/x)*x).toFixed(15);
1.2
```

Edit: *It would be better to use big.js.*

## [big.js](https://mikemcl.github.io/big.js/)

> A small, fast, easy-to-use library for arbitrary-precision decimal arithmetic.

```
>> bigX = new Big(x)
>> bigY = new Big(y)
>> bigY.div(bigX).round().times(bigX).toNumber() // => 1.2
```

Comment: Doesn't work for all combinations `y` and `x`.

Comment: toFixed returns a string

Comment: replace floor by round, `+` by parseFloat and 15 by a lower number if you can (toFixed argument could be calculated based on x)

Comment: Check also decimal.js or dinero.js for $

Comment: No need to use a library anymore. JS has native support for BigInt. Just use that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Answer (score 4):

```
> var x = 0.1
> var y = 0.2
> var cf = 10
> x * y
0.020000000000000004
> (x * cf) * (y * cf) / (cf * cf)
0.02
```

Quick solution:

```
var _cf = (function() {
  function _shift(x) {
    var parts = x.toString().split('.');
    return (parts.length < 2) ? 1 : Math.pow(10, parts[1].length);
  }
  return function() { 
    return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments, function (prev, next) { return prev === undefined || next === undefined ? undefined : Math.max(prev, _shift (next)); }, -Infinity);
  };
})();

Math.a = function () {
  var f = _cf.apply(null, arguments); if(f === undefined) return undefined;
  function cb(x, y, i, o) { return x + f * y; }
  return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments, cb, 0) / f;
};

Math.s = function (l,r) { var f = _cf(l,r); return (l * f - r * f) / f; };

Math.m = function () {
  var f = _cf.apply(null, arguments);
  function cb(x, y, i, o) { return (x*f) * (y*f) / (f * f); }
  return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments, cb, 1);
};

Math.d = function (l,r) { var f = _cf(l,r); return (l * f) / (r * f); };

> Math.m(0.1, 0.2)
0.02
```

You can check the full explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem).

Comment: Math.m(0.07, 100) => 7.000000000000002

Comment: This is not working!

Answer (score 2):

Check out this link.. It helped me a lot.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toprecision.asp

The `toPrecision(no_of_digits_required)` function returns a `string` so don't forget to use the `parseFloat()` function to convert to decimal point of required precision.

Comment: If you happened to be someone who downvoted me for this answer, could you please explain why ?  (the solution provided seems to work )

Comment: Basically the problem is this, you have js numbers y and x and you want the nearest (from y) multiple of x. The toPrecision method doesn't help i.e. `parseFloat((150).toPrecision(1)) === 200`

Comment: doing string/float-parsing conversion for a rounding problem isn't exactlxy what I would call performing at scale :D (better: implement/use a toPrecision function that operates/returns solely on numbers!)

Answer (score 1):

Tackling this task, I'd first find the number of decimal places in `x`, then round `y` accordingly. I'd use:

```
y.toFixed(x.toString().split(".")[1].length);
```

It should convert `x` to a string, split it over the decimal point, find the length of the right part, and then `y.toFixed(length)` should round `y` based on that length.

Comment: This gets a bit problematic of `x` is an integer.

Comment: Modern (>ES2020) version that works on floats and integers: `Number(x.toFixed(String(y).split('.')[1]?.length ?? 0)`