# Round float values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, floating-accuracy

I am trying to round a value in JS but I am getting not rounded value, this is what I have:

```
  $(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () {
              var agentPercentage = parseFloat($('#<%=ddlSplitPerc.ClientID%>').val()).toFixed(2);
              var percMod = 1.0 - agentPercentage;
              percMod = Math.ceil(percMod * 100) / 100;
              var dropdownAgentPerc = $('#<%=ddlPercSplitAgent.ClientID %>');
              dropdownAgentPerc.val(percMod);
             dropdownAgentPerc.change();           
             $('#AddNewSplitAgentLife').modal('show');
          });
```

For example, the agentPercentage is 0.7 and when I am subtracting 1 - 0.7 I am getting this value:

> 0.30000000000000004

What do you think I should change? I tried the `Math.cell` example as well but I am getting 0.31 as a result.

Comment: So you're saying that you're surprised that floating point mathematics are not precise on a computer?

Comment: This tells you why you're getting that result: [Is JavaScript's Floating-Point Math Broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is in another question already asked: [Dealing with float precision in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695618/dealing-with-float-precision-in-javascript)

```
(Math.floor(y/x) * x).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: thx for your answer but how can I utilize that formula in my case? I am not doing any dividing, I tried (Math.floor(1 - 0.7) * 1) but I am getting 0 as a result. Thanks

Comment: You only need the `.toFixed(2)` part.

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you subtract .5 from the value you pass to Math.ceil

```
percMod = Math.ceil((percMod * 100) -.5 )/ 100;
```

Math.ceil will round up for any decimal above .000

So to simulate the typical rounding behavior of only rounding decimals above .500 you should subtract .5