# Restrict Float Precision in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, fixed-point

I'm working on a function in JavaScript. I take two variables x and y.

I need to divide two variables and display result on the screen:

```
x=9; y=110;
x/y;
```

then I'm getting the result as :

> 0.08181818181818181

I need to do it with using some thing like `BigDecimal.js` that I found in another post.

I want that result was shown as:

> 0.081

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dealing with float precision in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695618/dealing-with-float-precision-in-javascript)

Comment: which in turn is duplicate for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this it is rounding to 3 numbers after coma:

```
(x/y).toFixed(3);
```

Now your result will be a string. If you need it to be float just do:

```
parseFloat((x/y).toFixed(3));
```

Comment: Yes but note that `.toFixed()` returns a string, not a number. May not matter here of course.

Comment: Yes, I wonder now how it's matter if:

     var x = (9/110).toFixed(3);
     console.log(x);
     console.log(x*24);
     console.log(x/45);
     console.log(x--);

all of this works even if it is string. When does it matter? Thanks

Comment: @kajojeq, if you are doing like `(9/110).toFixed(3) === 0.082` it will return false

Comment: @smerny 
Yes you right. I am not often using `===` and `==` still gives true. thanks for fast reply!

Comment: *"When does it matter?"* Try `x + 42`.

Comment: Right, added line with parsing to float if needed. Hope now It's clear. thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can do this

```
Math.round(num * 1000) / 1000
```

This will round it correctly. If you wish to just truncate rather than actually round, you can use `floor()` instead of `round()`

Answer (score 4):

Use this to round 0.818181... to 0.81:

```
x = 9/110;
Math.floor(x * 1000) / 1000;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var num = x/y;
parseFloat((Math.round(num * 100) / 100).toPrecision(3))
```

Comment: You should be aware that this question is a year old, with an accepted answer and multiple possible duplicates.  Therefore, you should take extra care to demonstrate how your answer is more useful than the already provided responses.

Answer (score 0):

if i'm use the simple expression, result may be unexpected:

```
const fraction = (value) => {
  return value - Math.floor(value);
}
fraction(1 / 3);
=> 0.333333333333 // is Right
fraction(22 / 3);
=> 0.33333333333333304 // is Unexpected
```

So, my robust expression is:

```
const fraction = (value) => {
  return parseFloat(value.toString().replace(/^\d+$/, '0').replace(/^.+?(?=\.)/, ''))
}
fraction(22 / 3);
=> 0.333333333333333
fraction(1111)
=> 0
fraction(.122211)
=> 0.122211
fraction(11111.122211)
=> 0.122211
fraction(11111.12)
=> 0.12
fraction(11111.11112)
=> 0.11112
```