# -webkit-box-shadow not changing properly with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
var oneHeight = Math.ceil(0.012*window.innerHeight).toString()+"px";
var usboxshadow="0px "+oneHeight+" 0px rgba(0,140,255,1), 0px "+oneHeight+" 25px rgba(0,0,0,.7)";
console.log(usboxshadow);
$(".unselected").css("-webkit-box-shadow",usboxshadow);
```

When I output **usboxshadow** to the console, I get what I should:

```
0px 20px 0px rgba(0,140,255,1), 0px 20px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.7)
```

(the -webkit-box-shadow property)
However, when I retrieve the property with Jquery.css(),

```
console.log($(".unselected").css("-webkit-box-shadow"));
```

I get a very different result:

```
rgb(0, 140, 255) 0px 20px 0px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.701961) 0px 20px 25px 0px
```

First, where did the extra 0px come from in each of the arguments?

Second, why is the rgba alpha(opacity) 0.701961, when it should be 0.7?

Please tell me what I have done wrong.

**Edit**:

After running the code, the box-shadow of the elements with the class *unselected* doesn't display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Updated for second question, see at the bottom.**]

1) In CSS, you can specify the `box-shadow` by using two, three or for pixel values.
First two are **x,y offsets**, two others are **spread value & radius**. See [MDN for more infos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow).

When you set a CSS rule (with CSS or jQuery), the browser automatically put full values (in this case, four `px` values). That's why you get the extra one when targetting with jQuery: the last one is given by the browser default behaviour (see the [computed panel](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/elements-styles) in Chrome inspector: it shows you values you didn't have to set because they are default ones).

2) *.7* or *.701961* isn't very different. I think your code seems good, but sometimes, conversion issues can exists in float numbers (= decimals). The way a computer stores a decimal number may vary following various complex criterias, I think. See [this subject on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695618/dealing-with-float-precision-in-javascript).

I think you should'nt worry about that. There's maybe a way to force proper conversion in JS or jQuery. Can't tell more.

Hope I could help. :)

### Update

Here are experimentations on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qjdwrzfn/2/) (updated version than my Comment on this answer). The problem comes from `var oneHeight = Math.ceil(0.012*window.innerHeight).toString()+"px";`

I didn't paid much attention to it (sorry), but what `window.innerheight` returns is the height of the Window. Therefore, the *y offset* of the shadow will vary depending on the browser window size. That's why we obtain a very different shadow.

Once again, I have no other explanations for the decimal issue. ^^

Comment: Another thing, after applying this box shadow css, it doesn't affect the element with the class unselected ... (+1)

Comment: OK I found the problem by experimenting on [this JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qjdwrzfn/). I'll update the base answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Good answer. I would expand that jQuery has nothing to do with it — you could do it with javascript `HTMLElement.style` and get the same result: http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/50eLezko/.

Comment: Updated the Fiddle linked in my previous comment. Updated the answer. :)

Comment: (BTW, I realize it doesn't really solve your shadow not applying to the unselected class. Maybe my answer will put you on the way, maybe you could provide a bunch of HTML ^^.)