# Javascript create number upto 17 decimal places

Tags: javascript, numbers, decimal

I have to create a JavaScript Number containing 17 decimal places. I used the following code :

```
var integerPart  = "10";
var roundedDigits = "12345678912345678";
var x  = Number(integerPart + '.' +  roundedDigits);
```

Output:
10.123456789123457

But when I try to output this number object, I get max of 15 decimal places. How can I achieve this?

Comment: "Decimal" numbers are actually floats. Floats are an *imprecise* data type. Do you require any amount of precision of your values? Then you need to use strings. Only use floats if you don't mind values getting rounded or losing precision.

Comment: You should take a look at [Math.js](http://mathjs.org/) library, this is awesome to do what you want.

Comment: More precisely [here](http://mathjs.org/examples/bignumbers.js.html)

Answer (score 0):

all numbers in javascript are double. they have a maximum of 16 digits.
you need a special datatype like [BigDecimal](https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js)

see this answer

[Dealing with float precision in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695618/dealing-with-float-precision-in-javascript)

and 
[IEEE floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)