# Subtracting float values gives negative results

Tags: javascript

I was trying simple subtraction of float values and I got a weird output of negative zero:

```
var pay = -0.33;
var res = parseFloat(pay) + parseFloat(0.11) + parseFloat(0.22);
res = res.toFixed(2);
console.log(res);
```

output: `-0.00`

Comment: What's weird about it? The actual number is `-2.7755575615628914e-17`. It's that small that when you convert it to string via `toFixed(2)` that the result is `0.00`. The sign shows that it has been rounded up from a negative number.

Comment: there are already multiple js parsing float values questions: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695618/dealing-with-float-precision-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

Nothing strange here, this is how IEEE floating point works.

Since what you seem to be doing here is formatting a currency value, I would suggest writing a reusable function to do that so it's done consistently throughout your app.

There are several approaches, however which to use depends on the application

It's not a bug. There is nothing wrong with -0 as a value in IEEE floating point: -0 === 0,  x + -0 = x, x * -0 = -0 etc.
In arithmetic minus 0 works exactly the same way 0 does.

Usually I would handle the -0.00 when formatting, since only -0.00 "looks wierd", -10.20 is just an overdraft :)

```
res = res.toFixed(2);
if(res === '-0.00'){
  res = '0.00';
}
```

I suggest this article to understand IEEE floating point better: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 0):

javascript and machine in total handle with double as almost infinite number.

when rounding to 2 decimal places, javascript gives the nearest rounded number.

to fix it, use:

```
var pay = -0.33;
var res = parseFloat(pay) + parseFloat(0.11) + parseFloat(0.22);
res = res.toFixed(2);
return (Math.round(res * 100) / 100);
```

way better than other's workarounds here will evaluating strings..

**EDIT**

if you change the round number, better use this:

```
var fixRound = 2,
    pay = -0.33,
    rounding = Math.pow(10, fixRound),
    res = parseFloat(pay) + parseFloat(0.11) + parseFloat(0.22);
    res = res.toFixed(fixRound );
    return (Math.round(res * rounding ) / rounding );
```

this way, all you need to change in the code in order for it to work with toFixed(3), toFixed(4),toFixed(5) and so on, is just set `fixRound` value to be the number you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I found to prevent toFixed to return negative zero:

`fixed_toFixed = (value, prec) => Math.abs(value) < Math.pow(10, -prec) ? (0).toFixed(prec) : value.toFixed(prec);`

Answer (score -1):

Actually what is happening here is that there is no initial positive number greater than or equal to the negative number. if you want to get a positive value as a result then the positive number should be greater than or equal to the negative number
What i am trying to say is :
if you do this:
-0.33-0.11+0.44 then you will get a positive zero value as there is an initial positive value greater than all the negative numbers.