# Math.pow(64, 1/3) returns inexact 4

Tags: javascript, math, precision

I was playing around with `Math.pow()` today in JavaScript, when I noticed that:

1. `Math.pow(8, 1/3)` and `Math.pow(27, 1/3)` return 2 and 3, respectively
2. `Math.pow(64, 1/3)` and all other higher perfect squares return long approximate floating point numbers, such as 3.99999999999999996.

[image: Test in Google Chrome's Developer Tools' Console]

I've heard of floating point precision and how some decimals can appear inexact, but this stood out to me because it only happens beginning at four cubed (64). Can anyone please explain why this happens?

Comment: It is a general problem with floating pioint precision http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695618/dealing-with-float-precision-in-javascript also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Comment: @ArunPJohny I was just wondering why it didn't happen with `Math.pow()` to find the cube roots of 1, 8, and 27, but only with the others?

Comment: Because it's not a cube root, it's a power of `0.(3)`

Comment: "why it didn't happen with Math.pow() to find the cube roots of 1, 8, and 27, but only with the others" --- error accumulates.

Comment: @zerkms A power of `0.(3)` or `1/3` is equivalent to the cube root.

Comment: @JonathanLam it is not. `0.333333333333333333...` is not exactly equal to the fraction `1/3`. JS does not have a type to represent fractions.

Comment: @zerkms That clears it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.13) does not make any guarantees regarding the precision of result returned by `Math.pow`. It states:

> Returns an implementation-dependent approximation to the result of
>   raising x to the power y.

So what you are getting might be different for different implementations.

I assume that the deviation in cube roots of 1, 8 and 27 from the exact 1, 2 and 3 respectively is so small that it doesn't reflect as a fraction in the result. But when the number under consideration becomes large, so does the error associated with it.

Notice:

```
Math.pow(1000,1/3)
-> 9.999999999999998

Math.pow(1000000,1/3)
->99.99999999999997
```

It will keep on deviating from the whole number value.

Comment: Thanks! Nice example

Comment: I just found a edge case where it returns an extra decimal place:
`Math.PI * Math.pow(21, 2)` vs `Math.PI * 21 * 21` 