# Calculation in JQuery gives result "NaN"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to do some calculations using jquery:

Run the below snippet: put values

> Quantity as **1**
>
> Buy as **111**
>
> Sell as **111.22**

The result will be **NaN**.

Why this is happening? How to resolve this issue?

```js
function roundToTwo(num) {
  return +(Math.round(num + "e+2") + "e-2");
}


$("#quantity, #buy, #sell").on("change keyup paste", function() {
  var quantity = Number($('#quantity').val());
  var buy = Number($("#buy").val());
  var sell = Number($("#sell").val());


  var total_amnt_trade = roundToTwo((quantity * buy) + (quantity * sell));
  var brokerage_amnt_buy = ((buy * quantity) * 0.08) / 100;
  if (brokerage_amnt_buy >= 25) {
    var brokerage_buy = 25;
  } else {
    var brokerage_buy = brokerage_amnt_buy;
  }
  var brokerage_amnt_sell = ((sell * quantity) * 0.08) / 100;
  if (brokerage_amnt_sell >= 25) {
    var brokerage_sell = 25;
  } else {
    var brokerage_sell = brokerage_amnt_sell;
  }
  var brokerage = roundToTwo(brokerage_buy + brokerage_sell); //brokerage
  var transaction_charges = roundToTwo((((buy * quantity) + (sell * quantity)) * 0.00325) / 100); //Transaction Charges
  var gst = roundToTwo((((transaction_charges * 18) / 100) + (brokerage * 18) / 100)); //GST

  var total_charges = roundToTwo(brokerage + transaction_charges + gst);
  var pnl = roundToTwo(((sell - buy) * quantity) - total_charges);

  $('#pnl_display').text(pnl);


})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="table table-borderless">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
      <td><b>Quantity</b></td>
      <td><b>Buy</b></td>
      <td><b>Sell</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" name="quantity"></td>
      <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="buy" placeholder="Buy Amount" name="buy"></td>
      <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="sell" placeholder="Sell Amount" name="sell"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="pnl_color">
      <td><span id="pnl_text_display">Profit / Loss</span></td>
      <td><span id="pnl_display"></span></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Run the above snippet: put values

> Quantity as **1**
>
> Buy as **111**
>
> Sell as **111.22**

The result will be **NaN**.

Why this is happening? How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Profit/Loss is showing 100.1 for me not NaN

Comment: If I enter 111.22 the input will show with a red border as soon as I blur it.

Comment: It can't, by manual calculation also it will not be that much... @RK_15

Comment: @RK_15 If you input the OPs values, you will  get NaN

Comment: @orever, there are quite a few calculations happening, did you try debugging your code?

Comment: seems problem in roundToTwo, if you pass something already turn into science notation, + make two "e" in string and cant be transfer back to number

Comment: Just update your one line as `var pnl = roundToTwo((roundToTwo(sell - buy) * quantity) - total_charges);` then it will work.

Comment: @waynelpu so what's the best option for it?

Comment: @orever how many precision you need? how about round twice `Math.round(Math.round(1.005 * 1000)/10)/100`

Comment: @waynelpu Run this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnpeyd61/3/)

Comment: @orever as i ask you, how many precision you need?, in computer science especially js, float number has it's precision limitation, you need to know what the precision you need in your real application

Comment: Till the last precision (as there is a limitation else I'll go for unlimited0, as even I also don't know how many I need as I will be added by calculating 4-5 different types of percentage...(in the question I have mentioned only 2-3).

Comment: @orever try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695618/dealing-with-float-precision-in-javascript)

Comment: I'll be thankful if you clear my doubts at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55631605/calculation-of-jquery-in-while-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `roundToTwo` you can use `.tofixed(2)` then problem resolves. Because your answer return with `e` (-1.1379786002407855e-15) so it shows `NaN`.

```
 var pnl = parseFloat(((sell - buy) * quantity) - total_charges).toFixed(2);
```

```js
function roundToTwo(num) {
  return +(Math.round(num + "e+2") + "e-2");
}


$("#quantity, #buy, #sell").on("change keyup paste", function() {
  var quantity = Number($('#quantity').val());
  var buy = Number($("#buy").val());
  var sell = Number($("#sell").val());


  var total_amnt_trade = roundToTwo((quantity * buy) + (quantity * sell));
  var brokerage_amnt_buy = ((buy * quantity) * 0.08) / 100;
  if (brokerage_amnt_buy >= 25) {
    var brokerage_buy = 25;
  } else {
    var brokerage_buy = brokerage_amnt_buy;
  }
  var brokerage_amnt_sell = ((sell * quantity) * 0.08) / 100;
  if (brokerage_amnt_sell >= 25) {
    var brokerage_sell = 25;
  } else {
    var brokerage_sell = brokerage_amnt_sell;
  }
  var brokerage = roundToTwo(brokerage_buy + brokerage_sell); //brokerage
  var transaction_charges = roundToTwo((((buy * quantity) + (sell * quantity)) * 0.00325) / 100); //Transaction Charges
  var gst = roundToTwo((((transaction_charges * 18) / 100) + (brokerage * 18) / 100)); //GST

  var total_charges = roundToTwo(brokerage + transaction_charges + gst);
  var pnl = parseFloat(((sell - buy) * quantity) - total_charges).toFixed(5);
 pnl = roundToTwo(pnl);
  $('#pnl_display').text(pnl);


})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="table table-borderless">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
      <td><b>Quantity</b></td>
      <td><b>Buy</b></td>
      <td><b>Sell</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" name="quantity"></td>
      <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="buy" placeholder="Buy Amount" name="buy"></td>
      <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="sell" placeholder="Sell Amount" name="sell"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="pnl_color">
      <td><span id="pnl_text_display">Profit / Loss</span></td>
      <td><span id="pnl_display"></span></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: see this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary#comment34941440_12830454) and the comment just below it.

Comment: do you need round value if third digit of after dot is less than 5?

Comment: @orever after converting float you can round it right for eg:`.toFixed(5)` then `Math.round` you can use or Check the updated answer.

Comment: So, what will be your updated code? (Better if the codes are edited in the function **roundToTwo** it self).

Comment: just I added `roundToTwo(pnl)` after converting to float. or if you use `(Math.round(num + "e+3") + "e-3")` it will works perfectly nothing issue

Comment: I'll be thankful if you clear my doubts at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55631605/calculation-of-jquery-in-while-loop

Answer (score 0):

I modified yout roundToTwo() function to handle precision errors:

```js
function roundToTwo(num) {
  return parseFloat(num.toFixed(2));
}


$("#quantity, #buy, #sell").on("change keyup paste", function() {
  var quantity = Number($('#quantity').val());
  var buy = Number($("#buy").val());
  var sell = Number($("#sell").val());


  var total_amnt_trade = roundToTwo((quantity * buy) + (quantity * sell));
  var brokerage_amnt_buy = ((buy * quantity) * 0.08) / 100;
  if (brokerage_amnt_buy >= 25) {
    var brokerage_buy = 25;
  } else {
    var brokerage_buy = brokerage_amnt_buy;
  }
  var brokerage_amnt_sell = ((sell * quantity) * 0.08) / 100;
  if (brokerage_amnt_sell >= 25) {
    var brokerage_sell = 25;
  } else {
    var brokerage_sell = brokerage_amnt_sell;
  }
  var brokerage = roundToTwo(brokerage_buy + brokerage_sell); //brokerage
  var transaction_charges = roundToTwo((((buy * quantity) + (sell * quantity)) * 0.00325) / 100); //Transaction Charges
  var gst = roundToTwo((((transaction_charges * 18) / 100) + (brokerage * 18) / 100)); //GST

  var total_charges = roundToTwo(brokerage + transaction_charges + gst);
  var pnl = roundToTwo(((sell - buy) * quantity) - total_charges);

  $('#pnl_display').text(pnl);


})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="table table-borderless">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
      <td><b>Quantity</b></td>
      <td><b>Buy</b></td>
      <td><b>Sell</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" name="quantity"></td>
      <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="buy" placeholder="Buy Amount" name="buy"></td>
      <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="sell" placeholder="Sell Amount" name="sell"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="pnl_color">
      <td><span id="pnl_text_display">Profit / Loss</span></td>
      <td><span id="pnl_display"></span></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnpeyd61/1/) and this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55625345/calculation-in-jquery-gives-result-nan#comment97950358_55625525)

Comment: Please see if this [implementation](https://jsfiddle.net/cqb6dLze/) solves your issue

Answer (score 0):

@Orever can you try again after replacing the line ( return +(Math.round(num + "e+2") + "e-2"); ) with ( return +(Math.round(num * 100) / 100); ) in the function roundToTwo(num).
So your code will be

```
function roundToTwo(num) {
   return +(Math.round(num * 100) / 100);
}
```

Comment: See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnpeyd61/) and this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary#comment24719818_11832950)