# Calculation of JQuery in while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Trying to calculate Break Even Point (BEP) using jquery:

```js
function roundToTwo(num) {
  return +(Math.round(num * 100) / 100);
}
var text = ""
var quantity = 1;
var buy = 0;
var sell = 10;
var bep_pnl = -0.5;
if (buy == 0) {
  buy = roundToTwo(sell - 0.01);
  while (bep_pnl < 0.01) {
    total_amnt_trade = roundToTwo((quantity * buy) + (quantity * sell));
    var brokerage_amnt_buy = ((buy * quantity) * 0.08) / 100;
    if (brokerage_amnt_buy >= 25) {
      var brokerage_buy = 25;
    } else {
      var brokerage_buy = brokerage_amnt_buy;
    }
    var brokerage_amnt_sell = ((sell * quantity) * 0.08) / 100;
    if (brokerage_amnt_sell >= 25) {
      var brokerage_sell = 25;
    } else {
      var brokerage_sell = brokerage_amnt_sell;
    }
    var brokerage = roundToTwo(brokerage_buy + brokerage_sell); //brokerage
    var transaction_charges = roundToTwo((((buy * quantity) + (sell * quantity)) * 0.00325) / 100); //Transaction Charges
    var gst = roundToTwo((((transaction_charges * 18) / 100) + (brokerage * 18) / 100)); //GST


    var total_charges = roundToTwo(brokerage + transaction_charges + gst);
    bep_pnl = roundToTwo(((sell - buy) * quantity) - total_charges);

    text += "<br />New Buy " + buy + " and profit " + bep_pnl;

    buy = roundToTwo(buy - 0.01);
  }
  var bep = roundToTwo(sell - buy);
  $('#demo').text(bep);
  document.getElementById("testing").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="demo"></p>
<h1 id="testing"></h1>
```

While running the above codes the result of **BEP** is **0.04**. But it should be **0**.

---

I think it's a technical problem (maybe in **while loop**) as the formula is correct. (Can be cross-checked in `<h1>`

Comment: Do you have a technical problem with your code or is your formula wrong? what's the question here?

Comment: @empiric it's a technical problem. (updated question [last lines])

Comment: Well I don't know if I understand that correctly but in demo you set `bep = roundToTwo(sell - buy)` but in the H1 it`s ` bep_pnl = roundToTwo(((sell - buy) * quantity) - total_charges);`, is that intentional? Additional the varibble `buy = roundToTwo(buy - 0.01);` get overriden after the H1 is set

Comment: It's just for understanding. @empiric [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnpeyd61/5/) of **pnl** instead of **~bep_pnl~**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's that extra `buy = roundToTwo(buy - 0.01);` *before* the while loop expires that's giving the .04 result. You need to decrement buy at the *beginning* of the loop, not the end. Set `buy = sell` before it enters the while, then move `buy = roundToTwo(buy - 0.01);` to the beginning of the loop.

That would give .03 as the result of `var bep = roundToTwo(sell - buy);`, which is consistent with the output `New Buy 9.97 and profit 0.01`.