# Adding javascript numbers does not have effect

Tags: javascript, floating-point

```
let x = -75;
let b = -7.105427357601002e-15;
x = x + b;
alert(x);
```

Alert prints -75. Why? What is the solution to avoid this error?

Comment: You've basically said -75 + 0. That number is so small it's essentially 0. Do you actually need precision to 15 decimal places?

Comment: The number you are adding is too small, JavaScript can't calculate it with its vanilla libraries.
Search for some BigDecimal library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dealing with float precision in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695618/dealing-with-float-precision-in-javascript)