# How to perform j operations on array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array of integers, what's the most efficient way to perform `j` operations on the array where the value of `j` could be `=>` or `<=` `array.length`?

I tried something like this...

```js
function performJ(arr, j) {
  arr.sort((a, b) => b - a);
  let i = 0;
  while (j !== 0) {
   if (i < arr.length) {
     arr[i] = Math.ceil(arr[i] / 2)
   } else {
     // when i reaches arr.length, reset it to continue operations j
     i = 0;
     arr[i] = Math.ceil(arr[i] / 2)
   }
   // increment i, step through arr
   ++i;
   // decrement j as we perform operations on arr
   --j;
 }
 return arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
}
```

That works for a lot of cases, but for some reason it seems like large inputs of `arr` and `j` cause arithmetic operations in the `while` loop to get way off.

Thanks!

*EDIT:* Edited question for clarity. I previously had a solution that worked, but it took way too long. This solution's arithmetic is off, but works much faster.

Comment: "the most efficient way" in terms of what? Also what is `arr.someMethod();`?

Comment: What do you mean by "to get way off"?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko -- Efficient in terms of time.

Comment: @Dekel -- Small inputs of `arr` and `j` work for something like sorting the array and reducing the sum of its elements, very large inputs produce incorrect answers for those operations.

Comment: Can you give an example of such an input for which the result is incorrect? I tried a few but they seemed to work as desired

Comment: If you want a solution for the first paragraph, then check out @CertainPerformance 's answer. Your numbers going way off has nothing to do with the first paragraph. Your array of integers aren't really integers but double precision floats and is causing this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695618/dealing-with-float-precision-in-javascript

If you really want to work with integers, use the new BigInt type or use an arbitrary precision math library.

Comment: The `i` is guaranteed to be an integer. The second argument `j` sounds like it should be as well, even if the number is large.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yep, the elements of `arr` are guaranteed to be integers, so is `j`

Comment: I don't think it's `j` and `i` that stop being integers but the result of this expression `arr[i] / 2` , which is why I'm guessing OP added `Math.ceil()` around it.

Comment: @KerimGüney -- the values returned when the function completes are integers, but they're incorrect in that they're much larger than the expected values. For the small inputs, the values are correct, for large inputs some return values are far greater than expected.

Answer (score 4):

Use modulo to iterate on indicies `[i % arr.length]` from 0 to `j`:

```
function performJ(arr, j) {
  arr.someMethod(); // ?
  for (let i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    arr[i % arr.length] = /* operation */
  }
  return arr.someMethod(); // ?
}
```

Comment: When `j` exceeds array length, it simply loops back to the remainder value (aka modulus). Not sure why there's a downvote tho... :/ this is a great answer.

Comment: Oddly enough, this solution fails in just the same way as my original code. I updated my question for more clarity on what I'm trying to do. My first solution worked, but took too long, so it's not a true "solution", but the one I shared above fails on larger inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just a for loop like this?

```
for(let i = 0; i <= j; i++) {
  const index = i % array.length;
  array[index] = doSomething();
}
```

if `array.length` is 5 but `j` is 3 then `doSomething()` will only be called on the first three elements. if `array.length` is 3 but `j` is 5 then `i` will reach 3 and `3 % 3 === 0` so `index` will loop back to the beginning.  That means `doSomething()` will be called on all three elements once and during the second run on only the first two elements.

Is this what you want?