# How do I round cart total in React.js to 2 decimal places?

Tags: reactjs, math

I have a React.js shopping cart with 4 items, each item has a different value to 2 decimal places like so:

```
Item 1 = price:0.50
Item 2 = price:0.30
Item 3 = price:0.20
Item 4 = price:0.15
```

When I add Item 1 (value of 0.50) to the cart it adds correctly and I can add several of Item 1 to the cart and it will always remain to 2 decimal places. However, if I add any of the other 3 items to the cart, on the third addition to the cart it returns a number that isn't rounded (i.e 3x Item 2 should = 0.90 but it returns 0.8999999999999999).

**cartReducer.js:**

```
import Item1 from './images/apple_gala.jpg';
import Item2 from './images/apple_greenleaf.jpg'
import Item3 from './images/apple_granny.jpg'
import Item4 from './images/apple_pinklady.jpg'
import { ADD_TO_CART, REMOVE_ITEM } from '../actions/action-types/cart-actions.js'

const initState = {
    items: [
        {id:1,title:'Royal Gala', desc: "Gala apples have a blush of pink in their skin. It’s dense, sweet juicy flesh makes it ideal for eating fresh.", price:0.50, SKU:'A',img: Item1},
        {id:2,title:'Greenleaf', desc: "Our own original produce, the Greenleaf Original apple is award winning for the crispness of it's skin.",price:0.30, SKU:'B',img: Item2},
        {id:3,title:'Granny Smith', desc: "Our French Granny Smith apples have a distinct sharp taste – perfect for eating fresh or using in cooking.", price:0.20, SKU:'C',img: Item3},
        {id:4,title:'Pink Lady', desc: "A distinct and refreshing flavour with uniquely pink colouring - it can only be our Pink Lady apples.", price:0.15, SKU:'D',img: Item4},
    ],
    addedItems:[],
    total: 0

}
const cartReducer= (state = initState,action)=>{

    if(action.type === ADD_TO_CART){
          let addedItem = state.items.find(item=> item.id === action.id)

         let existed_item= state.addedItems.find(item=> action.id === item.id)
         if(existed_item)
         {
            addedItem.quantity += 1 
             return{
                ...state,
                 total: state.total + addedItem.price 
                  }
        }
         else{
            addedItem.quantity = 1;

            let newTotal = state.total + addedItem.price 

            return{
                ...state,
                addedItems: [...state.addedItems, addedItem],
                total : newTotal
            }

        }
    }
    if(action.type === REMOVE_ITEM){
        let itemToRemove= state.addedItems.find(item=> action.id === item.id)
        let new_items = state.addedItems.filter(item=> action.id !== item.id)

        let newTotal = state.total - (itemToRemove.price * itemToRemove.quantity )
        console.log(itemToRemove)
        return{
            ...state,
            addedItems: new_items,
            total: newTotal
        }
    }

  else{
    return state
    }

}

export default cartReducer
```

**CartAjax.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Recipe from './Recipe.js'
import { removeItem,addQuantity,subtractQuantity} from './actions/cartActions'
import KeyboardArrowUpIcon from '@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowUp';
import KeyboardArrowDownIcon from '@material-ui/icons/KeyboardArrowDown';
import ClearIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Clear';

class CartAjax extends Component {

    handleRemove = (id)=>{
        this.props.removeItem(id);
    }

    handleAddQuantity = (id)=>{
        this.props.addQuantity(id);
    }

    handleSubtractQuantity = (id)=>{
        this.props.subtractQuantity(id);
    }

    render(){

        let addedItems = this.props.items.length ?
            (  
                this.props.items.map(item=>{
                    return(

                        <li className="collection-item avatar" key={item.id}>
                            <div className="item-img"> 
                                <img src={item.img} alt={item.img} className=""/>
                            </div>

                            <div className="item-desc">
                                <li className="cart-ajax-left"><span className="title">{item.title}</span></li>
                                <li className="cart-ajax-left"><span className="price">Price: £{item.price}/pu</span><span className="SKU">SKU: {item.SKU}</span></li>
                                <p>
                                    <b>Quantity: {item.quantity}</b> 
                                </p>
                                <div className="add-remove">
                                    <Link to="/"><i className="material-icons" onClick={()=>{this.handleAddQuantity(item.id)}}><KeyboardArrowUpIcon/></i></Link>
                                    <Link to="/"><i className="material-icons" onClick={()=>{this.handleSubtractQuantity(item.id)}}><KeyboardArrowDownIcon/></i></Link>
                                </div>
                                <div className="remove-icon" onClick={()=>{this.handleRemove(item.id)}}><ClearIcon/></div>
                            </div>      
                        </li>
                    )
                })
            ):

             (
                <p>You must be hungry, order something...</p>
             )
       return(
            <div className="Cart-ajax">
                <div className="cart">
                    <h5>Your Order:</h5>
                    <ul className="collection cart-placeholder">
                        {addedItems}
                    </ul>
                </div> 
                <Recipe />
            </div>
       )
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state)=>{
    return{
        items: state.addedItems,
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch)=>{
    return{
        removeItem: (id)=>{dispatch(removeItem(id))},
        addQuantity: (id)=>{dispatch(addQuantity(id))},
        subtractQuantity: (id)=>{dispatch(subtractQuantity(id))}
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(CartAjax)
```

**Recipe.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
//import { addShipping } from './actions/cartActions'
class Recipe extends Component{

    componentWillUnmount() {
         if(this.refs.shipping.checked)
              this.props.substractShipping()
    }

    handleChecked = (e)=>{
        if(e.target.checked){
            this.props.addShipping();
        }
        else{
            this.props.substractShipping();
        }
    }

    render(){

        return(
            <div className="container results">
                <div className="collection">
                    <li className="collection-item">
                        <span className="shipping">Excl. Shipping (£2.95)</span>
                    </li>
                        <li className="collection-item sub-total-value"><b>Order Total: £{this.props.total}</b></li>
                    </div>
                    <div className="checkout">
                        <button className="checkout-btn">Checkout</button>
                    </div>
                 </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state)=>{
    return{
        addedItems: state.addedItems,
        total: state.total
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch)=>{
    return{
        addShipping: ()=>{dispatch({type: 'ADD_SHIPPING'})},
        substractShipping: ()=>{dispatch({type: 'SUB_SHIPPING'})}
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Recipe)
```

The `cartReducer.js` contains the price variables, these are rendered through `Recipe.js` which is included via `<Recipe />` in the `CartAjax.js` file.

I am assuming I need a `Math.round()` type function. My question is can I achieve this in React.js and if so how?

Comment: Try this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Number/toPrecision

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dealing with float precision in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695618/dealing-with-float-precision-in-javascript)

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad not specifically for React, I knew I was looking for a Math.round function, it was the syntax that was wrong - see my below answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.round(your final value)
```

this can help you to achieve the result your expecting

check this out for further reference [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

& react can't do this ideally

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out, you can use inline jS functions in React such as `.toFixed(2)` where (2) represents the number of decimal spaces. So in `Recipe.js` where the total value is called you can do:

```
<li className="collection-item sub-total-value"><b>Order Total: £{this.props.total.toFixed(2)}</b></li>
```

---

```
{this.props.total.toFixed(2)}
```