# Seemingly inconsistent toFixed() behavior

Tags: javascript, tofixed

I know the toFixed() function isn't meant to be used for rounding, but I still can't seem to make sense of why it sometimes rounds up and sometimes rounds down when the number ends in .5

Take a look at these examples:

**toFixed(0) example**

```js
(0.5).toFixed(0)
> '1' // round up

(1.5).toFixed(0)
> '2' // round up

(2.5).toFixed(0)
> '3' // round up

(3.5).toFixed(0)
> '4' // round up

(4.5).toFixed(0)
> '5' // round up

(5.5).toFixed(0)
> '6' // round up

(6.5).toFixed(0)
> '7' // round up

(7.5).toFixed(0)
> '8' // round up

(8.5).toFixed(0)
> '9' // round up

(9.5).toFixed(0)
> '10' // round up
```

Consistent behavior for this example.

---

**toFixed(1) example**

```js
(0.05).toFixed(1)
> '0.1' // round up

(1.05).toFixed(1)
> '1.1' // round up

(2.05).toFixed(1)
> '2.0' // round down

(3.05).toFixed(1)
> '3.0' // round down

(4.05).toFixed(1)
> '4.0' // round down

(5.05).toFixed(1)
> '5.0' // round down

(6.05).toFixed(1)
> '6.0' // round down

(7.05).toFixed(1)
> '7.0' // round down

(8.05).toFixed(1)
> '8.1' // round up

(9.05).toFixed(1)
> '9.1' // round up
```

This is where things start to break down. It seems like the first digit affects the rounding for some reason. Sometimes it rounds up and sometimes it rounds down.

---

**toFixed(2) example**

```js
(0.005).toFixed(2)
> '0.01' // round up

(1.005).toFixed(2)
> '1.00' // round down

(2.005).toFixed(2)
> '2.00' // round down

(3.005).toFixed(2)
> '3.00' // round down

(4.005).toFixed(2)
> '4.00' // round down

(5.005).toFixed(2)
> '5.00' // round down

(6.005).toFixed(2)
> '6.00' // round down

(7.005).toFixed(2)
> '7.00' // round down

(8.005).toFixed(2)
> '8.01' // round up

(9.005).toFixed(2)
> '9.01' // round up
```

Even stranger is that it's not always the same first digits that affect the rounding. You can see the results here are similar to the toFixed(1) example, but not exactly the same.

---

Is this a bug, some kind of browser issue, or expected behavior?

My system:

- Apple M1 Pro
- Chrome Version 116.0.5845.187

Comment: Keep in mind that the value you see without `.toFixed()` is itself a string produced by the `.toString()` conversion method for numbers. "Ends in .5" isn't necessarily an accurate description of the value; it might end in `.49378`.

Comment: For readability, I would actually wrap the number in parens .e.g. `(0.005).toFixed(2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually expected behavior with floating point precision in JS, as well as many other programming languages.

Here's a stack overflow thread discussing. [Dealing with float precision in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695618/dealing-with-float-precision-in-javascript)

Comment: Perhaps vote to close as duplicate of that instead of a link only answer (the quotedis a duplicate of another which is a duplicate of yet another etc.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss It's the same reasoning, but a completely different question. I knew about floating point precision before, but I didn't realize it was the underlying reason for my problem here. I don't think the other question inherently answers my question without being pointed out like Scott did here.

Comment: Fair enough; adds to the searchable related things anyway with the reference AND your valid comments

Answer (score 0):

You could use my following code to round numbers to some decimal point with up to 10 decimals (the bigger you could get some rounding errors from `toFixed()`:

```js
const round = (num, digits = 2, precision = 10) => {
  const str = num.toFixed(precision), idx = str.indexOf('.');
  if (idx < 0) return num;
  const left = str[idx + 1 + digits]; // round this char
  if (!left || left === '0') return num;
  return parseFloat(str.slice(0, idx + 1 + digits)) + 
      (left >= 5) * (str[0] === '-' ? -1 : 1) / 10 ** digits;
}

const toFixed = (num, decimals = 2) => round(num, decimals).toFixed(decimals);

[[0.0000000049, 9], [6.5, 0], [1000000.0000055, 6], [0.0000055, 6], [0.0049555, 4], [6.05, 1], 35.855, 35.8549999, [-35.8549999, 3], 35.895, 35.8, 35].forEach(num => 
  console.log(JSON.stringify(num), '->', toFixed(...[].concat(num))));
```